# Format datetime in java based on locale

Tags: java, datetime, localization, date-formatting

I want the date and time to be formatted based on the criteria(below objects) for each datetime component. And the separators between them should be taken based on locale. Is there way to achieve this in java

```
   { year: numeric, month: long, day: two-digit, weekday: short }   
   { year: numeric, month: twoDigit, day: twoDigit }
   For example consider second object and locale Locale.US and Locale.FRANCE.
   For Locale.US date should be 26/03/2024
   For Locale.France date should be 26.03.2024
```

I know I can use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate()`, which gives me the choice of four format styles for each locale, from short to full. I am after the greater flexibility of specifying for each field whether it should be numeric or textual and how long, the same that I can when specifying a format pattern string, but still with the right delimiters for the locale.

Comment: You may be able to get that through [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedPattern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedPattern(java.lang.String)) since Java 19.

Comment: I tried `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedPattern("yMMMMEEEdd").withLocale(Locale.US)`, which indeed creates a `DateTimeFormatter`. But when I tried formatting a `LocalDate` with it, I got `DateTimeException: Requested template "yMMMMEEEdd" cannot be resolved in the locale "en_US"`. I can’t tell what goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To represent a date, use `LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.MARCH , 26 ) ;
```

To generate text, use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object.

To specify a particular format, define a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
String output = localDate.format( f ) ;
```

To automatically localize while generating text, use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate(java.time.format.FormatStyle)). Specify a `FormatStyle` and a `Locale`.

For more complicated matters, use the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class to generate a `DateTimeFormatter` object.

Your Question is a bit too vague to say more. To learn more, search Stack Overflow as these topics have been addressed many times already.

Comment: How to localize the delimiters . (like / - . ).

Comment: @ChinnmayBS Delimiters are handled by `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate` as mentioned above. Read the documentation linked above.

Comment: I want custom format other than(FULL,LONG,MEDIUM,SHORT) along with locale for delimiters. like (MMM delimiter yyyy ) delimiter based on locale.

Comment: @ChinnmayBS Why would you want to use the locale-recognized delimiter but then violate the cultural norms for the order of the parts, and other aspects? For example, your text `26/03/2024` for US locale is quite confusing to an American reader.